# Error: WorkflowScript: 1: unexpected token: < @ line 1, column 1. on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, svn, jenkins-pipeline, tortoisesvn, collabnet

I am working on Multibranch pipeline job over Collabnet Subversion Repository. When after a new setup of Multibranch job, It met the criteria of Jenkinsfile. But the build fails on the branches.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
    
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                //ws('C:/Path'){
                    echo 'BranchOne'
                //}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above is in my Jenkinsfile.

The below is the error received during the execution of build.

```
Started by user Naveen
Opening connection to http://SVN-URL
Obtained Jenkinsfile_RelativePath/ from 18
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 1: unexpected token: < @ line 1, column 1.
   <html><head><title>CollabNet Subversion Repository: RepositoryName - Revision 18: /trunk/Jenkinsfile_RelativePath</title></head>
   ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:309)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addFatalError(ErrorCollector.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:119)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:131)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.addError(SourceUnit.java:349)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:191)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:189)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:966)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:626)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:602)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:579)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:293)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox$Scope.parse(GroovySandbox.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:142)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:127)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:563)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:515)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:336)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:107)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:449)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Is there a problem with repository permissions or any other issues?

Comment: You seem to be using an incorrect SVN URL, which outputs only an HTML view of a repository. Make sure you are using the real SVN URL for checkouts.

Comment: URL is the correct one

Comment: Does ist work when you check out manually, using an SVN client?

Comment: Yes I can able to check out manually